# Azure DevOps build using Docker becoming progressively slower

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building multiple projects using a single **docker build**, generating an image and pushing that into AWS ECR.  I've recently noticed that builds that were taking 6-7 minutes are now taking on the order of 25 minutes.  The Docker build portion of the process that checks out git repos and does the project builds takes ~5 minutes, but what is really slow are the individual Docker build commands such as `COPY`, `ARG`, `RUN`, `ENV`, `LABEL` etc.  Each one is taking a very long time resulting in an additional 18 minutes or so.  The timings vary quite a bit, even though the build remains generally the same.

When I first noticed this degradation Azure was reporting that their pipelines were impacted by "abuse", which I took as a DDOS against the platform (early April 2021). Now, that issue has apparently been resolved, but the slow performance continues.

Are Azure DevOps builds assigned random agents?  Should we be running some kind of cleanup process such as `docker system prune` etc?

Answer (score 0):

> Are Azure DevOps builds assigned random agents? Should we be running some kind of cleanup process such as docker system prune etc?

Based on your description:

```
The timings vary quite a bit, even though the build remains generally the same.
```

This issue should still be a performance problem of the hosted agent.

And based on the settings of Azure DevOps, every time you run the pipeline with host-agent, the system will randomly match a new qualified agent. Azure DevOps builds assigned random new agent, so we do not need run some kind of cleanup process.

To verify this, you could set your [private agent](https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fagents%2Fv2-windows%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26viewFallbackFrom%3Dvsts&data=04%7C01%7CCuan.Leo%40clouddirect.net%7Ca81f3286da28484ccf5008d8e893e92d%7C2d2006bf2fde473c8ce4ea5307e8eb99%7C0%7C0%7C637515069284628639%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=W4acuID6yw9mvRr6iuFKyLxoT0jYFP3MnbHYIAvfcl8%3D&reserved=0) to check if the build time is much different each time (The first build time may be a bit longer because there is no local cache resource).

By the way, if you still want to determine whether the decline in hosted performance is causing your problem, you should contact the Product team directly, and they can check the region where your organization is located to determine whether there is degradation in the region.